# Curl Request with -d command

Tags: php, curl, libcurl

I want to execute curl command with `-d` to send SMS using Africa Talking API unfortunately i can't get any response from the server rather in the response body there's `false` Please help me how to send the request am new to curl.

Here is the curl sample from https://build.at-labs.io/docs/sms%2Fsending

```
curl -X POST \
    https://api.sandbox.africastalking.com/version1/messaging \
    -H 'Accept: application/json' \
    -H 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
    -H 'apiKey: MyAppApiKey' \
    -d 'username=MyAppUsername&to=%2B254711XXXYYY,%2B254733YYYZZZ&message=Hello%20World!&from=myShortCode'
```

**And to my understanding bellow is what i implemented**

```
$messages = array(
    'username'=>'sandbox', //rather my username
    'to'=>$phone, // 266XXXXXXX,266XXXXXX
    'message'=>$text,//Hello
    'from'=>$from //Sandbox
);

$url = "https://api.sandbox.africastalking.com/version1/messaging";
//$url="https://api.africastalking.com/version1/messaging";
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    'Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    'apiKey:my-api-key'
));

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, ($messages)); //json_encode($messages)

$server_output = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

var_dump($server_output);
```

Output `false`

Comment: The curl command line command works? When curl_exec() returns False it means that the request could not be sent and so there can't be any server response at all.

Comment: I tested your code. It says `The requested resource could not be found.`

Comment: Meaning the URL is not valid?

Comment: @Stack: Proxy, network problems or something else. As Amanjot stated your code works and returns a string, not False. So if this exact code returns False on your machine, it is not the code, it is likely the connectivity.

Answer (score 1):

You need to build a query string in order for you to send the data successfully to the endpoint. That means changing

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, ($messages)); //json_encode($messages)
```

to

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($messages)); //json_encode($messages)
```

Answer (score 0):

Curl is ok....I think the problem is with AfricasTalking documentation. However this worked for me.

```sh
 curl -X POST https://api.sandbox.africastalking.com/version1/messaging -H 'Accept: application/json' -H 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' -H 'apiKey: MyAppApiKey' -d username=MyAppUsername&to=%2B254711XXXYYY,%2B254733YYYZZZ&message=Hello%20World!&from=myShortCode'
```

if you are not using a sandbox app you should use the live version instead as shown below.

```sh
curl -X POST https://api.africastalking.com/version1/messaging -H 'Accept: application/json' -H 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' -H 'apiKey: MyAppApiKey' -d username=MyAppUsername&to=%2B254711XXXYYY,%2B254733YYYZZZ&message=Hello%20World!&from=myShortCode'
```